# App.all doesn't fire on static file access?

Tags: node.js, express

In my server.js I have:

> app.all("*", function(req, res, next) {
>
> ```
>     // only gets called when I'm doing a post/get request
> ```
>
> next(); });

But I'd like to get an event when a static file, such as an html file was accessed on my server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a static file serving middleware such as `express.static`, then you will have to place your route/middleware above that for it to get triggered. Express executes middleware in the order they are defined.

Comment: can you provide an example of what you mean, I just have app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/public')); I did place it before the app.all call

Comment: No, you need it the other way around. Your `app.all` has to be placed *before* your `express.static` because `express.static` does not continue the request down the chain if it finds a file that matches the request's path.